# jQuery page transition but keep "open in new tab"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy there,
I noticed several pages with a pretty sweet page transition (one example: [semplice](http://www.semplicelabs.com/))

if you click the navigation the page fades out, reloads and fades back in. Now I tried to create something on my own. I created the effects for the fadeIn and the fadeOut. Then I created something like this:

```
$(function(){
    fadeInbody();
    $('ul#navi li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        fadeInbody(function(){
            window.location = newLocation;  
        });
    });
});
```

Actually that works quite good for the normal left-click.

But now I have a mousebutton that opens the link automatically in a new tab. I use this button quite a lot. In this case because of the `e.preventDefault();` it breaks this behaviour and opens the page the same tab.

Is there a better to create something like this without breaking the default behaviour? (In the semplice-example the new tab mousebutton works)

Comment: When you say mousebutton, what are you referring to specifically?

Comment: `if(e.which != 1) return; e.preventDefault(); etc...` if i understand what you mean

Comment: Well in this case I mean the mousewheel. But I've also seen mice who have it as a button..

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks! That's it! Is this cross browser compatible?

Comment: @NicoMartin This is normalized in jQuery: `event.which also normalizes button presses (mousedown and mouseupevents), reporting 1 for left button, 2 for middle, and 3 for right. Use event.which instead of event.button.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check which button the user has clicked in the event's `which` property.

So, your code would look like this:

```
$(function(){
    fadeInbody();
    $('ul#navi li a').click(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            newLocation = this.href;
            fadeInbody(function(){
                window.location = newLocation;  
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You basically run your fade logic when the user clicks with the left button.

See comments below the question for cross-browser compatibility info.